# Set page size for WPF PrintDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I'm trying to print from a WPF application, but struggling to set a default page size.

The content I'm printing is supposed to be on a C5-sized envelope, and most printers here default to A4 paper.

I'd like to show a dialog to the user to allow them to choose the printer to use - but if they just press OK to accept the default printer, it defaults to A4 paper.

How can I set the print defaults for a job to C5 envelop?
Can I still prompt the user for the printer?

```
private void PrintVisual_Sized(UIElement toPrint)
{
    PrintDialog dlg = new PrintDialog();
    PrintQueue queue = dlg.PrintQueue;

    // Get C5 page size if possible from printer
    var availPageSizes = queue.GetPrintCapabilities().PageMediaSizeCapability;
    PageMediaSize pageSize = Utilities.GetPageSize(availPageSizes, PageMediaSizeName.ISOC5Envelope);

    if (pageSize != null)
    {
        PrintTicket ticket = new PrintTicket
        {
            PageMediaSize = pageSize,
            InputBin = InputBin.AutoSelect,
            CopyCount = 1
        };

        dlg.UserPageRangeEnabled = false;

        var result = dlg.PrintQueue.MergeAndValidatePrintTicket(dlg.PrintTicket, ticket);
        Debug.Print(result.ConflictStatus.ToString());

        // Try to get the page size honoured by someone!!!
        dlg.PrintQueue.DefaultPrintTicket = result.ValidatedPrintTicket;
        dlg.PrintQueue.UserPrintTicket = result.ValidatedPrintTicket;
        dlg.PrintTicket = result.ValidatedPrintTicket;

        // Height still seems to be A4 sized!?
        Debug.Print("Height: " + dlg.PrintableAreaHeight);
    }

    // Ask user which printer they want...
    if (dlg.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault(false))
    {
        Size printSize = new Size(dlg.PrintableAreaWidth, dlg.PrintableAreaHeight);
        toPrint.Measure(printSize);
        toPrint.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(), printSize));
        toPrint.UpdateLayout();

        dlg.PrintVisual(toPrint, "My Print Job");
    }
}
```

In the last section `printSize` is A4 unless the user manually selects another paper size.
Is there any way to display the dialog, with a non-default page size preset?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I'd love to know how you got past this issue.